# How to stop execution of shell code when jar inside throws an error?

Tags: shell

I have a jar which I run via shell script. But if jar throws some error (we are supposed to update jar in that case) the shell script just continues processing the next line and the error is lost in logs.

Can I stop the execution of shell script when ever jar throws an error?

```
cd correctDirectory
....../bin/java -cp myjar.jar package.mainclass
#The below should not execute when the above jar throws an error.
Number=$(wc -l outputOfJar.txt)
#insert the above number in DB which if is less than a threshold generates me an alert
#But this is not so effective.
```

Comment: Can you paste your shell code in yourpost?

Comment: look at `set -e` option for shell (stop on processing on any error). Good luck!